# Update a set of records based on count - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I have a 100 active records in my table - cars. The user has decided to downgrade their account and is now eligible to only have 5 active records. I need to set the expiration date on 95 records (oldest first) to current timestamp. How do I do this in MySQL - bonus thanks if you include some cakephp hints (but I will thank you for just the SQL hint alone)

Here is what I tried but I get an error message stating that mySQL does not support LIMIT in sub-query

```
UPDATE cars 
SET archived = NOW()
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM cars
    ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 5
)
```

Comment: How is PHP and cakephp related to the question?

Comment: My application layer is in CakePHP - that is why I mentioned 'bonus' thanks - but if I get a pure SQL solution, I am fine with that too...

Comment: Then please remove those tags

Comment: Actually, I would like some hints (if possible) on writing this query in pure CakePHP (which is SQL platform independent) - hence the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-restrictions.html) does not explain why LIMIT clauses in this type of subquery is not supported. However, there is no such limitation on sub-subqueries.

To resolve this issue, lets create another subquery and move the LIMIT clause into it:

```
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
      FROM (
        SELECT id 
          FROM cars 
          ORDER BY created 
          DESC LIMIT 5
      )
      AS carsInner
)
```

The innermost query will select only the last five rows, and exists only to satisfy the requirement that the subquery should not contain the limit clause.

The final query looks like:

```
UPDATE cars 
  SET `archived` = NOW()
  WHERE id NOT IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM (
          SELECT id 
          FROM cars 
          ORDER BY created 
          DESC LIMIT 5
        )
        AS carsInner
    );
```

[See an SQL Fiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cefa91/1).

Comment: Thank you George - question - is this a performance issue if i have say 10000 records that I will be updating? Or is it negligible. For practical reasons, I dont anticipate my data volume exceeding 100000 records

Comment: The additional subquery will add some overhead, but this can be partially offset by making sure that you have indexes on `id` and `created`. To get the best information on performance, consider benchmarking the query on your system with a large number of rows to see if it performs within the time limits specified by your SLAs.

Comment: If benchmarks reveal that the query speed will be problematic, given that this query happens only when an account is downgraded, perhaps it can be queued to run during off-peak hours.